# Get category image to a page template

Tags: template, magento-1

I have created a new page template here:

**/template/page/category.phtml**

and copied inside the content of **1column.phtml**.

What I want to accomplish is to get the category data variable in this new template.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<html>
<head>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('head') ?>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Instead of getting the category content through the function below, I want to get it without this function-->
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: could you please let me know what exactly you want? do you want category thumbnail and small image or all data?

Answer (score 11):

you need to load category on your template. Either by factory method(as shown here) or in your block instantiation( {{block }} or xml block ). I hope this code snippet will help.

```
$_helper    = $this->helper('catalog/output');
$_category  = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(CATEGORYID);// get your category here.
$_imgHtml   = '';
if ($_imgUrl = $_category->getImageUrl()) {
    $_imgHtml = '<p class="category-image"><img src="'.$_imgUrl.'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($_category->getName()).'" /></p>';
    $_imgHtml = $_helper->categoryAttribute($_category, $_imgHtml, 'image');
    echo $_imgHtml;
}
```

Comment: Note: Missed a ' in 'catalog/category