# Display only third level category

Tags: magento-1.9, category

My categories are displayed this way:
- Main Category
  - Product type
    - Brand

I want to display the image of the third level category on the homepage.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: So do you confirm that you want to display the Brand category image on your homepage ? That's all ? I reckon you can get it easily following this post: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26006/get-category-image-to-a-page-template

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to load the category:

```
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(89);
```

Replace 89 with the ID of the category you are interested in loading, then you will have access to the full range of attributes belonging to that category including the Image (if any) associated to it.

Answer (score 0):

Test it, it's my nav code (without div) :

```
<?php
$layer = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/layer');
$_category = $layer->getCurrentCategory();
$currentCategoryId= $_category->getId();
$_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category');
$_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories();
$currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category');

if (count($_categories) > 0){
foreach($_categories as $_category){ 
  $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()); 
  $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();

  if (count($catList) > 0){ 
    $subcat=0

    foreach($catList as $_subCategory){ 
    $_subSubCat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_subCategory['id']);
    $_subSubCategories = $_subSubCat->getChildrenCategories();

      if (count($subCatList) > 0){ 
        foreach($subCatList as $_subSubCat){ 
        echo $_subSubCat->getName();                             
      }; 
    };
    };  
    }; 
  }; 
};
```