# Fetch Category Image

Tags: magento-1.7, category, image, if

I am attempting to **display all sub-categories of a parent category** on a static block page (e.g. brands will show all sub-categories such as Adidas, Nike etc.). I am having problems at the moment **calling the category image**. It is the category image I am looking for and **not the thumbnail**.

Here's my code:

```
                    <?php 
                    //If there are sub categories
                    $categories = $this->getCurrentChildCategories();
                    $categoriescount = $this->getCurrentChildCategories()->count();
                    if ($categoriescount > 0): 
                    ?>
                    <div class="sub-category-container">    
                        <?php 
                        //Loop through categories
                        foreach ($categories as $category):
                        ?>
                        <div class="sub-category">
                            <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="cat-image">
                            <?php 
                            // If there is a thumbnail set for the category - Display it
                            if($imgUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getThumbnail()):?>
                            <img src="<?php echo $this->getBaseUrl()."media/catalog/category/".$imgUrl ?>" width="220" height="110" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($category->getName()) ?>" />
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="inner-sub-category">
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="sub-link"><?php echo $category->getName()?></a>
                                <a href="<?php echo $this->getCategoryUrl($category)?>" class="btn"><span>View All</span></a>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php else:?>
                    <p>No Sub Categories</p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Not sure if this helps but appears to be answered here? [http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26006/get-category-image-to-a-page-template](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26006/get-category-image-to-a-page-template)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was as simple as changing this line from 'Thumbnail' to 'Image':

```
 if($imgUrl = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category->getId())->getImage()):?>
```